# Finding Substring of Number with certain property

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am given a string consisting of only numbers from 0 to 9. I want to calculate how many sub strings of them are power of 2.

For example for substring 2560616 substring 256 and 16 are power of 2. I need to calculate how many such substrings are there in any given substring.

Note that the substring is very large so brute force can't work. So I mainly want to address 2 issues

1. How to efficiently count all substrings that are power of 2
2. How to efficiently calculate whether a substring is power of 2

I think there might be a DP approach, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: How long of a string are you talking about? It makes a difference in what the best approach is.

Comment: @Coda17 String length is upto 10^5

Comment: Unless you can come up with some fancy mathematical algorithm, I think your best bet is to branch and prune.  The difficulty comes with pruning as early as possible.  But making sure to immediately ignore any string that ends in an odd number is a start.  You could also pre-calculate all powers of two to make matching any string to a power of two only have O(1) time complexity.

Alternatively, you could pre-calculate all powers of two and then  use regular expressions to search for every occurrence of the numbers you calculate.

Comment: In your example, what about the substrings "2" and "1"?

Comment: @NiklasB.yes i forgot to mention it. Can you help with solution

Comment: I won't answer any of your questions in the future without reference to the source

Comment: Just an observation you have to look only substrings ending with 1,2,4,6,8 only . Might reduce some time but will be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a tree from the digits of the powers of 2 with the following algorithm:

1. Start with a root representing the empty character.
2. Get the next power of 2, get its digits in reverse order.

   1. Select the root. Select the last digit of the current number.
   2. Go to the child node of the selected node corresponding to the selected digit. If it does not exists yet, create it.
   3. Select the previous digit of the current number. Repeat from (2.) until there are no more digits.
   4. Mark the current node as a valid endpoint.
3. Repeat from (2.) until number of digits > 10^5

This tree might take a couple GBs in the memory.

Now you have your tree. To count the number of substrings that are power of 2, do the following:

1. Start from the end of the string.
2. Get the previous character.

   1. Select the root of the tree.
   2. Select the previous character (starting with the one selected in the outer (2.)).
   3. Select the child node of the selected node corresponding to the selected digit.
   4. If the selected child node is marked as valid endpoint, increment count by 1.
   5. Repeat from (2.) until selected node is null or reached first character of the string.
   6. Go back to character selected in outer (2.)
3. Select previous character. Repeat from (2.) until reached beginning of string.

The description of the algorithm is not "exam-ready", but i hope its understandable enough.

Comment: So basically you suggest in step 1 to to build a trie out of the strings representing powers of two. The problem is that building this trie will cost Omega(n^2) time, which is slow for n = 10^5.

Also, your search procedure is wrong in case of overlapping strings, which certainly occur within powers of two (e.g. 1 is a prefix of 1024 and 2 is a suffix of 32). What you would actually need is a [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) automaton, which is essentially the trie you describe, but with suffix links.

Comment: @NiklasB. "The problem is that building this trie will cost Omega(n^2) time, which is slow for n = 10^5" - it is, but you only need to build it once. If you only want to search a single line, there are probably better ways, but if you want to apply the search multiple times, you will get back the time invested into building the tree pretty fast. Also note that if you do choose Aho-Corasick automaton, you should go backwards in the string. That way you will get a smaller tree (powers of 2 can start with any digit, but the n-th digit from the back is restricted)

Comment: @NiklasB. "Also, your search procedure is wrong in case of overlapping strings" - its not. Even thought its not as sophisticated as the Aho-Corasick automaton, it solves the overlapping string problem with step (6.)

Comment: In any case, O(n^2) is easy to achieve, just do a simple linear time pattern search for every power of two. No need for a trie or anything (and also with only O(n) additional space. It would be interesting to see whether there is an o(n^2) approach.

Comment: @NiklasB. There is a difference between building a tree in O(n^2) and using it to search linearly and running every search with O(n^2) complexity (assuming you want to search more than 1 sequences)